# Rendering mailer templates with Mustache in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, mustache

I'm trying to port my Rails email templates over to mustache using the [stache gem](https://github.com/agoragames/stache).

I have a standard mailer action which simply sends an email to a user. I've renamed my template path in order to prevent a naming clash when I create the stash view class for the template associated with this mailer action. This process is outlined in [the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views).

```
# app/mailers/registration_mailer.rb
class RegistrationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def bailed(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, template_path: 'er_registration_mailer'
  end
end
```

This is the Stache view associated with the action above. Notice that the module name matches the template path above.

```
# app/views/er_registration_mailer/bailed.rb
module ErRegistrationMailer
  class Bailed < ::Stache::Mustache::View
    def continue_registration_link
      link_to "Continue registration by connecting your Twitter account", 
        connect_registrations_url
    end

    def signature
      @view.render "shared/mailer/sig"
    end
  end
end
```

Finally I have a mustache template for my mailer.

```
# app/templates/er_registration_mailer/bailed.html.mustache
<p>Hi there!</p>

<p>I noticed you recently started the signup process for my app but didn't complete it.</p>

<p>{{{continue_registration_link}}}</p>

{{{signature}}}
```

When I try to send an email, I get an error when it tries to render the `signature` partial. This partial lives in `app/templates/shared/mailer` where I have both mustache and erb versions of it called `_sig.html.mustache` and `_sig.html.erb` respectively.

Here's the error:

```
Failure/Error: RegistrationMailer.bailed(user).deliver
  ActionView::Template::Error:
    Missing partial shared/mailer/sig with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :slim, :arb, :rb, :mustache]}. Searched in:
      * "/Users/davidtuite/dev/shareshaper/app/app/views"
      * "/Users/davidtuite/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/bundler/gems/active_admin-6f04ed5cec24/app/views"
      * "/Users/davidtuite/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"
      * "/Users/davidtuite/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-rails-5.0.3.1/app/views"
      * "/Users/davidtuite/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views"
  # ./app/views/er_registration_mailer/bailed.rb:17:in `signature'
```

Rails appears to be searching in `app/views` for the template (or view class, I'm not sure which).

How can I get the partial to render correctly?

I'm using Rails 4.0.3, Ruby 2.1.1 and stache 1.0.3.

**Things I've tried**

Using the wrapper class functionality of the stache gem instead of specifying the `template_path` to mailers and prefixing the name spacing of the view class.

I've tried both:

```
# app/views/registration_mailer/bailed.rb
module Wrapper
  module RegistrationMailer
    class Bailed < ::Stache::Mustache::View
    end
  end
end
```

and (note the directory structure):

```
# app/views/wrapper/registration_mailer/bailed.rb
module Wrapper
  module RegistrationMailer
    class Bailed < ::Stache::Mustache::View
    end
  end
end
```

But I just get an `Uninitialized const: Wrapper` error.

I've also tried using mustache to specify the partial in the mailer template:

```
# app/templates/er_registration_mailer/bailed.html.mustache
<!-- HTML as in above code sample -->

{{{>shared/mailer/sig}}}
```

That just gives me a different 'not found' error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of using Stache with a mailer:

```
# config / initializers / stache.rb
Stache.configure do |c|
  c.template_base_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'views')
  c.wrapper_module_name = "Wrapper"

  c.use :mustache
end

# app / mailers / registration_mailer.rb
class RegistrationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default template_path: 'mailers/registration_mailer'

  def bailed(user)
   @user = user
   mail to: user.email
 end
end

# app / models / wrapper / mailers / regisration_mailer / bailed.rb
module Wrapper
  module Mailers
    module RegistrationMailer
      class Bailed < ::Stache::Mustache::View
        def continue_registration_link
          link_to "Continue registration by connecting your Twitter account", 
            connect_registrations_url
        end

        def signature
          @view.render "shared/mailer/sig"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I think what you are missing is the need to configure both the wrapper module and the template path.